# Rotation of X-axis by 180 degrees

Tags: geometry, coordinates

Rotating Y-axis about 180 degrees cause a flip for X and Z. Is that also valid that rotating about the X-axis 180 degrees cause a flip for Y and Z?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not related to programming

Comment: It is still relevant for game programming. Please do not block from the helping hands.

Comment: Then please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to answer the question

Comment: Do you mean a rotation *about* the y-axis instead of a rotation *of*  the y-axis? In this case, yes. Rotating 180° about one of the principal axes will flip the other two.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: Yes, i meant 'rotation about the y-axis'. Thanks for the answer.